# Can't Boot either Windows 10 or Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: boot, dual-boot, 18.04, partitioning, uefi

I have an HP Laptop, a [Pavilion 15-cs1000tx](http://h10032.www1.hp.com/ctg/Manual/c05493762), recently bought in February. It  came with Windows 10 preinstalled. Since it was not working well for me, I thought of installing Ubuntu 18.04 to use in a second partition, after I did that, I was not able to boot in any of the OS.

When I checked the BIOS setting, I found there was an entry before "OS Boot Manager", that was gone and there is no option that says - "Boot from harddisk" in UEFI boot order.

Even when I change to "Legacy Support", it never boots up. So I thought of installing the clean Ubuntu 18.04 in the whole partition, removing the whole Windows from my machine, still, there is no change, I still get "there is no boot device or boot loader failed".

I have applied all of my knowledge whatever I gained from the internet to fix this. I also tried - efibootmgr to change the boot order, but nothing worked for me, finally now I logged in using Ubuntu Live USB and change the boot order to  Ubuntu first (using efibootmgr -n XXXX), but now I can't shut down or restart my machine. It is running from the installed ubuntu from the hard disk, but it is a temporary fix, until I find a solution to boot from my hard disk.

I am pretty sure there is no problem with the hard disk because I can access my installed Ubuntu, but to access that I need to use the Live USB to change the boot order for the next time. But the boot order is not retained if I shutdown or restart.

I will be very glad if someone can help me with this. If there is any way we can disable the UEFI from the BIOS or we can add Ubuntu in the UEFI boot order list, anything that can fix this.

I have no idea why this Windows Boot Loader went away. Because I am pretty sure while installing Ubuntu in the first place, I did not touch anything related to Windows.

Additional Info:

I installed Ubuntu in the UEFI mode, instead of Legacy Support. Images have been added in the comment section. Please help.

Comment: When you say "I did not touch anything related to Windows", when installing along side Windows you have to install grub into the Windows ESP partition. If you didn't do that then I think that is how your problem started!

Comment: UEFI is what replaced BIOS a long time ago. Knowing this you should now understand how nonsensical the last part of your question sounds. When the first issue happened, the first thing to do would be checking the UEFI settings for changes regarding the boot order (this UEFI settings is the thing you understand as BIOS settings, but again, this is inaccurate). This is also the first thing you should check NOW, instead of using the EFI manager.

Comment: Please don't use the word 'nonsensical', that sounds too harsh. OP might not understand the system the way you do but take some time to explain and guide OP! @gabrielagarcia

Comment: "nonsensical" is an apt descriptor of anything that doesn't make sense, like a square circle, a married Batchelor or ***disable the UEFI from the BIOS***, it's not too harsh or even harsh at all, it's a mere neutral description of a logical impossibility.

Comment: Perhaps "illogical" would be better, please guide @gabrielagarcia

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I install Ubuntu alongside a pre-installed Windows with UEFI?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/how-do-i-install-ubuntu-alongside-a-pre-installed-windows-with-uefi) <- This is the guide :)

Comment: The PC's firmware configuration is often called the BIOS Setup, and in several different models I work with, there is, indeed, an option to turn off UEFI and go Legacy in what the manual calls the BIOS Setup. Yes, it's wrong, but also, some manufacturers are not making it easy for folks to learn when they use incorrect terminology.

Comment: _Gunny KC_, may I suggest you first reboot from a LiveUSB https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-create-a-usb-stick-on-windows#0 and take a look at how your system's `sda` drive is configured with the app gparted?  https://gparted.org/   Often, large manufacturers will put a 'recovery partition' there which may help you recover your Windows. Once Windows is back, then installing Ubuntu side-by-side alongside Windows is easy. You can upload the screenshot to https://imgur.com and then put a web link to the picture in the original question by clicking [edit]. Good night, Chesty.

Comment: Oh, and please flip it over and get the model number off the serial number plate, then use [edit] to put that in your question, too, because HP makes more models of Pavilions than the number of rounds in your Basic Load. That can help us find what features are in the BIOS, err, Firmware Setup, to change you back to UEFI https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/boot-to-uefi-mode-or-legacy-bios-mode , which is a far better way to set up a hard drive than Legacy BIOS Support.

Comment: @K&AAY - I will definitely mention everything in my answer, whatever you asked, but as I mentioned that I removed everything to install Ubuntu. I agree that I did not know much about this BIOS and UEFI, and made this mistake. The last time I worked with BIOS that had this option to switch from BIOS to UEFI or vice Versa. I did not think things have been so messy of late. I know I have ruined my settings, but still, I will try to provide everything you asked.

Comment: @K7AAY - looks like I have removed everything while installing Ubuntu. Please find the gparted image - https://imgur.com/Qy4nVyN. Is there any way I can fix this?  I can boot with Ubuntu only, I am fine with it, but it must boot smoothly. Let me know if this is possible, I have also added my laptop's exact model in my question. Let me know If I need to provide any other information.TIA.

Comment: @K7AAY - This is the O/P for efibootmgr - https://imgur.com/l3IW24K. If this can help a bit.

Comment: @K7AAY Other BIOS Info (https://imgur.com/uB547mW) and Boot Load Error Print Screen(https://imgur.com/PvEKDj9).

Comment: _Gunny KC_, the default settings of the firmware/BIOS normally work perfectly well with Ubuntu, especially UEFI. Windows 10 also wants UEFI. I can't review the pix now, but will later.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/94373/discussion-between-gunny-kc-and-k7aay).

Comment: Check this site for suggestions for dealing with HP's non-UEFI "features" like requiring specific names for the bootloaders.

Comment: @Fabby-no, it is not a duplicate, because I have already removed windows with ubuntu but the problem in my case is the boot loader. I am not able to boot Ubuntu from UEFI.